# Selenium IDE script can't find second select element on page

Tags: ajax, selenium, automation, browser-automation

I'm testing an Ajax app and have recorded a script in Selenium IDE 1.9.1 in Firefox 17. It generally works, but gets hung up at certain points. One issue I'm having is that the script correctly finds and selects the correct option from a select element (dropdown list). There is another select element directly below this one and for some reason, Selenium is saying it can't find that element (even though it's clearly there and the name is correct).

This is the code:

```
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>id=answerChoice7_8</td>
    <td>label=Massachusetts</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>id=answerChoice7_9</td>
    <td>label=Boston University - Boston</td>
</tr>
```

The first selection works fine, but for some reason, I get the following error when it tries to select the second one: "Element id=answerChoice7_9 not found". I check the element name using Firebug, and it's definitely answerChoice7_9.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium often has timing issues.  Since there is no page load in between selenium doesn't know to wait for the element to appear.  I think there is a command "waitForElementPresent".  Give that a try.

Comment: Selenium IDE really is only good as a teaching tool.  You will probably want to use Selenium with a programing language since the IDE is so limited.

Answer (score 0):

Add a command waitForElementPresent(id="answerChoice7_9") before select. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Does your html element have a name ?
If it has a name the command is `name=answerChoice7_9`